# How can I do groupy.apply() without sort my index?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the data like follow:

```
myData = pd.DataFrame({'K':[810,820,825,830,840,855,842,823],'Type':
['C','C','P','P','C','B','A','B'],'S':[978,978,978,978,978,966,925,923],'R':
[0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.03,0.04,0.05]})


    K   R   S   Type
0   810 0.05    978 C
1   820 0.05    978 C
2   825 0.05    978 P
3   830 0.05    978 P
4   840 0.05    978 C
5   855 0.03    966 B
6   842 0.04    925 A
7   823 0.05    923 B
```

I use `groupby` to get  this :

```
      K    R    S   Type
Type                    
A   6   842 0.04    925 A
B   7   823 0.05    923 B
C   0   810 0.05    978 C
P   2   825 0.05    978 P
```

But what I want is that the `Type` order do not change.

```
  K    R    S   Type
Type                    

C   0   810 0.05    978 C
P   2   825 0.05    978 P
B   7   823 0.05    923 B
A   6   842 0.04    925 A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sort = False` when using groupby for example

```
myData.groupby('Type',sort=False).mean()
```

```
            K     R      S
Type                         
C     823.333333  0.05  978.0
P     827.500000  0.05  978.0
B     839.000000  0.04  944.5
A     842.000000  0.04  925.0
```

Comment: Yeap,I finally got this!

Comment: Yeap,It needs time